# Flutter AutoResizeTextView, setting high fontSize overflows

Tags: dart, flutter

In Android, we can use `AutoResizeTextView` and give it any text size of our choice, it will not flow out of its constraints, I was looking for similar solution in Flutter.

I tried following,

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0, minWidth: 600.0),
  child: Text("8", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 400.0)),
);
```

Here is the ugly output. So, how can I force the `Text` to always stay inside the `Container` no matter how much `fontSize` is given to it

[image]

Comment: `FittedBox`? *"Scales and positions its child within itself according to fit."*

Comment: How can I specify the height in `FittedBox()`? Do I have to wrap it in `Container()`?

Comment: Worked. I wrapped that it in Container(), can you write it down as the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Thanks to pskink,

I need to wrap the `Text` inside `FittedBox` which is further wrapped inside a `Container`. Here is the solution.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200.0, minWidth: 600.0),
  child: FittedBox(child: Text("8", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 400.0))),
);
```

Comment: @pskink, you can write it down as answer too, I will accept yours not mine.